# How to use cursor in a trigger for delete in Firebird?

Tags: sql, cursor, firebird, database-trigger

I tried to write a trigger in Firebird in order to delete records from other tables automatically when I delete records from a table. Just like delete by cascade. For some reasons, there are some tables without primary keys.

The trigger is just like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG1_DEL_STEP_INFO FOR STEP_INFO
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE del_ID_IMAGE_INFO bigint;
DECLARE VARIABLE del_ID_FRAME_INFO bigint;

DECLARE del_cursor CURSOR FOR (SELECT ID_IMAGE_INFO, ID_FRAME_INFO FROM OLD);

    BEGIN

       OPEN del_cursor;

       WHILE (ROW_COUNT > 0) DO

         BEGIN

           FETCH del_cursor INTO del_ID_IMAGE_INFO, del_ID_FRAME_INFO;

             DELETE FROM FRAME_POLYGON WHERE ID_FRAME_INFO = :del_ID_FRAME_INFO;

             DELETE FROM FRAME_INFO WHERE RECID = :del_ID_FRAME_INFO;

             DELETE FROM IMAGE_INFO WHERE RECID = :del_ID_IMAGE_INFO;

             DELETE FROM IMAGE_FILE_INFO WHERE ID_IMAGE_INFO = :del_ID_IMAGE_INFO;

          END

         CLOSE del_cursor;
    END
```

But when I tried to put this into my Firebird DB by isql, I got a error like this:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42S02
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -204
-Table unknown
-OLD
-At line 6, column 73
```

Could you please to tell me how fix this problem?

Comment: "Just like delete by cascade. For some reasons, there are some tables without primary keys." So do delete by cascade. You do not need primary keys for it, you need FOREIGN keys. https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-constraints

Comment: @Arioch'The Sorry for late. Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I had tried to write a cascade on delete in STEP_INFO which looks like this:ALTER TABLE STEP_INFO ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_FRAME_INFO) REFERENCES  FRAME_POLYGON (ID_FRAME_INFO) ON DELETE CASCADE, but I got a error: Unsuccessful metadata update
could not find UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint in table FRAME_POLYGON with specified columns. So I had to write a trigger instead of a delete cascade.

Comment: If FK lacks UNIQUE constraint, then why cannot you add it too? Is your data non-unique on `FRAME_POLYGON( ID_FRAME_INFO )` ? Do you have there multi rows in that table with same value in this column ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, the problem is that there multi rows in that table with same value in this column. I can't change it, because the risk is too high.

Comment: if you have multi rows (with same `ID_FRAME_INFO`) in both `STEP_INFO` and `FRAME_POLYGON` then your action sounds very weird. Look, you delete one of many rows in `STEP_INFO`, but not all. Then your trigger deletes all rows in `FRAME_POLYGON`. And now you have a bunch of rows in `STEP_INFO` master table for which there is no data in `FRAME_POLYGON` details trigger. If that is what you need - then do triggers, but it sounds weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a cursor for this, nor do you need a cursor. Triggers in Firebird are fired per row, not per statement.

So instead you should do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG1_DEL_STEP_INFO FOR STEP_INFO
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM FRAME_POLYGON WHERE ID_FRAME_INFO = OLD.ID_FRAME_INFO;
    DELETE FROM FRAME_INFO WHERE RECID = OLD.ID_FRAME_INFO;
    DELETE FROM IMAGE_INFO WHERE RECID = OLD.ID_IMAGE_INFO;
    DELETE FROM IMAGE_FILE_INFO WHERE ID_IMAGE_INFO = OLD.ID_IMAGE_INFO
END
```

Comment: ...nor does he need a trigger to replicate foreign keys

Comment: @Arioch'The I considered that, but the problem seems to be that a link table is deleted and in response the associated primary key record needs to be deleted (given they are deleting from `FRAME_INFO` and `IMAGE_INFO` by the id from the trigger), so a `delete on cascade` seems to be out of the question (unless that link table could have a unique constraint on those fields individually). In itself it also seems to indicate an odd data model.

Comment: Yep, it is kind of funny, when he has two rows  in `STEP_INFO` with the same values in `ID_FRAME_INFO` and/or `ID_IMAGE_INFO` but only deletes one of those rows. /// at least I see no barriers from establishing cascading FK between IMAGE_INFO and IMAGE_FILE_INFO and between FRAME_POLYGON and FRAME_INFO in one or another direction

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Sorry for late. Thank you for your answer. I will try it.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel It works!! Thank you very much. [Triggers in Firebird are fired per row, not per statement]--There is the difference between Firebird and SQL Server.

Comment: @ballshark there are a LOT of differences. Start with reading somewhat obsoleted document of migrating to FB from MS SQL. There you would at least find hints to explore more about FB.